# How to get id values from listpicker?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I'm developing windows Phone 8 application.

In my app i use List Picker  .list picker value is bind from web service (json format)

My web service result return format

```
[
   - {
       id: "9",
       name: "Pizza",
       root_id: "4",
       level: "1"
     },
    -{
       id: "10",
       name: "Fine Dining",
       root_id: "4",
       level: "1"
     },
]
```

My XAML code for list picker

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="filterpicker"  SelectionChanged="filterpicker_SelectionChanged" Tap="filterpicker_Tap" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="395,-100,0,10"  Height="70" Width="60">

            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

My c# code for bind

```
 void filterwc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var filterdata = e.Result;
        var filtervalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<filterdatas>>(filterdata);
        List<string> filtercategories = new List<string>();
        foreach (filterdatas budval2 in filtervalue)
        {
          filtercategories.Add(budval2.id); /**I need to display the name and on selectionchanged event i need to get the id value**/
        }

        filterpicker.ItemsSource = filtercategories;
    }
```

if my question is not clear plz tell i give more info ...

I need Like this

List picker out put come like this

**Pizza**

**Fine Dining**

On SelectionChanged Event

if i click Pizza I need to get "9"

if i click Fine Dining I need to get "10"

Thank you...

Comment: You can do this a number of ways. If you wanted to do it the "Right way" You would use a converter class. If you wanted to do it the "Easy Way" Just bind the textbox tag value to the id you want. Then retrieve it in your back end with the selection changes

Comment: @AMR Plz show me some sample for converter class

Comment: That is a huge topic. Please do some research on your own There is a ton of examples on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

code Behind:

```
    var filterdata = e.Result;
    var filtervalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<filterdatas>>(filterdata);
    filterpicker.ItemsSource = filtervalue;
```

selection changed event

```
if(filterpicker.SelectedItem == null) 
   return;
filterdatas element = filterpicker.SelectedItem as filterdatas;
MessageBox.Show("This is the id:"+element.id);
```

Comment: Your code bind the name in list picker but how i get the Id of selected item on selection chaged event?

Comment: @Gurunathan edited with what to do in the selectionchanged eventhandler

Comment: How to clear the selected value in listpicker and set to default value