# Wp8 -list picker -filter second list picker values based on first list picker value

Tags: windows-phone-8, selecteditem, listpicker

I would like to get the value of a first listpicker and based on the its value filter the second list picker...Can anyone help me how to achieve it?

Comment: If the answer solves your issue please mark it a correct. If not let us know so we can help further.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on the programatically given 2nd list items?.the issue is that i need to have  5 to10 items ..which i should enter for the second list ...which is sorted based on the first option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
<StackPanel>
    <toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstPicker1" SelectionChanged="lstPicker1_SelectionChanged">
        <sys:String>Option 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Option 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Option 3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Option 4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Option 5</sys:String>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>

    <toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstPicker2">
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
</StackPanel>
```

Here as for the first ListPicker (lstPicker1) you can also set the items dynamically from the code as well.

I have created this method to dynamically create the content of the second `ListPicker` (lstPicker2). This is simple. Use something like this for your use

```
private List<string> CreateList(int opt)
{
    List<string> strLst = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        string str = string.Format("Sub-option {0}.{1}", opt, i);
        strLst.Add(str);
    }
    return strLst;
}
```

Then you use the `SlectionChanged` event from your lstPicker1 to set the items in the second `ListPicker`

```
private void lstPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lstPicker1 != null)
    {
        switch (lstPicker1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(1);
                break;
            case 1:
                lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(2);
                break;
            case 2:
                lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(3);
                break;
            case 3:
                lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(4);
                break;
            case 4:
                lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(5);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
     }
}
```

Here in the `SelectionChanged` method the If condition is need so it won't throw an `Exception` when the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

So you could simply use the `SelectionChanged` event to get the value of the selected value from the `ListPicker`.

[How to get id values from listpicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966182/)

[Listpicker error SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719682/)

Hope it helps!